# How to throw different messages when validating length and regular expression for a input text in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf-2, xhtml, validation

I have some code like this in my xhtml page

```
 <h:inputText    id="cardNumber"  
                 value="#{bean.cardNumber}" required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="Card Number Cannot be Blank" 
                 validatorMessage="Card Number must be 16 digits" 
                 maxlength="16" size="16" >   
        <f:validateLength  maximum="16" minimum="16" />   
        <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]*" for="cardNumber"/>
  </h:inputText>
```

For the above input text I am doing all three kinds of validation i.e required field validation,length validation,regular expression validation.

I understand that being I defined `validatorMessage` for `</h:inputText>`to validate `<f:validateLength/>` and `<f:validateRegex/>`,it throws the same message.How can I throw two different messages for  `<f:validateLength/>`and `<f:validateRegex/>`  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the `Messages.properties` file

Add the following entries and modify them...

```
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM = {1}: Validation Error: Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM = {1}: Validation Error: Length is less than allowable minimum of ''{0}''
```

and

```
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED = {1}: Validation Error: Value not according to pattern ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.PATTERN_NOT_SET = A pattern must be set for validate.
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.MATCH_EXCEPTION = The pattern is not a valid regular expression.
```

**For a complete tutorial take a look at this** : [Customize Validation Error Message In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/)

[And here a complete Reference to all available message that you can override in JSF 2.0.x](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/2.0.x/api/src/main/resources/javax/faces/Messages.properties)